# Imprimir con PHP resultado de consulta en mysql que contiene COUNT(), JOIN y Group By

Tags: mysql

Estoy enredado en un problema que se me presento, lo explico:

Tengo estas **3 Tablas** en mi BD:

**Bandas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Eventos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **Votacion**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para mostrar el resultado de las votaciones que estoy probando es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$EX_1  = $_POST['RV_EVENT'];

$RX_VOTE_EVENT = "SELECT vot_band_id,vot_event_id, COUNT(vot_id) AS total_votos 
FROM iw_votacion INNER JOIN iw_bandas_tributo ON iw_votacion.vot_band_id = 
iw_bandas_tributo.band_id INNER JOIN iw_eventos ON iw_votacion.vot_event_id = 
iw_eventos.evt_id WHERE vot_event_id='$EX_1' GROUP BY vot_band_id";
$SRX_VOTE_EVENT = mysqli_query($con,$RX_VOTE_EVENT);


if ($SRX_VOTE_EVENT) {
    while($rowX = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SRX_VOTE_EVENT)){ ?>
         <p><?php echo $rowX['band_nombre']; ?> Votos -> <?php echo 
$rowX['total_votos']; ?></p>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Pero como resultado me da lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como Resultado lo deseo lo siguiente:

```
Nirvana - Votos-> 3
AEEERRR - Votos-> 2
```

Comment: Ese error parece estar referido a poder o no leer los valores que le llegan de dichas variables, serías tan amable de mostrar de donde llegan y como llegan¿?

Comment: En la imagen del resultado donde indico el error, hay un input tipo select por el cual yo selecciono un evento y luego hago un POST con el boton calcular. Lo raro es que si me muestra la cantidad de votos: 3 y 2, pero no me muestra el nombre de la banda tributo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO estas incluyendo el nombre de la banda en la consulta:

```
$RX_VOTE_EVENT = "SELECT vot_band_id,vot_event_id, COUNT(vot_id) AS total_votos 
FROM iw_votacion LEFT JOIN iw_bandas_tributo ON iw_votacion.vot_band_id = 
iw_bandas_tributo.band_id LEFT JOIN iw_eventos ON iw_votacion.vot_event_id = 
iw_eventos.evt_id WHERE vot_event_id='$EX_1' GROUP BY vot_band_id";
```

aqui solo estas trayendo `vot_band_id,vot_event_id, COUNT(vot_id) AS total_votos`, agrega el campo del nombre